# How to pass the OTP read in broadcast receiver from xamarin droid to PCL?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I'm creating a mobileapp using xamarin forms. I'm using a broadcast receiver to read the sms for OTP Validation. After the message is received i'm getting the intent and i'm able to pull the otp from SMS, but how can i update the entry field in xaml page?

Comment: Xamarin Forms `MessagingCenter` may help you here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

Comment: Thanks! @jgoldberger. Achieved the functionality using MessagingCenter.